# Enter subdirectory if current directory is empty

Tags: bash, autocomplete, interactive

There is one thing that prevents me to discard my GUI-file manager for bash:
Bash does not tab-complete to the only subdirectory in an empty directory.

```
$ ls
..       // is not displayed, when cmd is simply ls
.        // but they still exist
subdir/
```

I want to be able to expand `cd <tab>`  into `cd subdir/` since there is nothing else in the current directory, but bash requires to type the first letter to complete this command.

**Use Case**
Navigating projects with nested directories (especially unkown ones) is painfully. /src/main/com/application/module/package translates to:
`s<tab><tab><tab>m<tab><tab><tab>c<tab><tab><tab>a<tab>...` where as in, e.g. thunar, the first directory is preselected, so i just can hit enter multiple times.

I guess this is due to the identifier of the current and parent directory. What would be the correct way to archice this behaviour in bash?

//edit_2:

I am using xfce4-terminal on Debian 10

Comment: What you're describing seems to be the default Bash behaviour as far as I can tell, so you may have it turned off in either your user configuration or the system bashrc (I don't know what setting that would be), or perhaps your shell isn't actually Bash. It is unusual for `ls` to include the `.` and `..` entries, also.

Comment: You are right, simply entering ```ls``` does not print ```.``` and ```..```, I will edit my question in this regards, but i am still required to input the first letter of the subdir

Comment: The described behavior is, [as Michael Homer said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579106/enter-subdirectory-if-current-directory-is-empty#comment1077829_579106), the default behavior already. The shell would only require you to type the first letter if the first letter is not unique, i.e. if the directory contains more than a single subdirectory (or file).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. I investigated my .bashrc's, /etc/bash.bashrc and .profile does not disable anything related to bash-completion. Maybe you could give me an hint, here is my config: https://github.com/thchha/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/.bashrc Also: I did not found an related option in the man of set (-o)

Comment: @Tomes It's probably *because* you're using bash-completion. bash-completion is a set of buggy scripts that override bash's default completion. I just don't use it anymore because it broke too many simple cases like this one.

Comment: Maybe not related but the utility `ranger` comes handy sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the quick comments to my problem. 
Disabling the shell-scripts for programmable shell-scripts resolved my issue.

It occurred due to an preinstalled package by Debian.
Steps to resolve this behaviour were:

1. get rid of the occurrences of the following code listing within my `.bashrc`-files, namely $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.profile, /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile.
2. get rid of the package via `apt remove bash-completion` which will remove the following files [Debian Packages - list files](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/bash-completion/filelist)
3. source the edited .bashrc / restart bash.

```bsh
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then  
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then  
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion  
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then  
    . /etc/bash_completion  
  fi  
fi
```

Thank you guys very much!